# React Native ReCaptcha harvester with --host-rules flag

Tags: react-native, appium, bots, recaptcha, detox

I have developed a Captcha Harvest Electron app which opens a Chromium browser using the flag:

```
--host-rules="MAP example.com 127.0.0.1:5555"
```

This maps the DNS record for `example.com` to `127.0.0.1:5555` rather than querying a DNS server for the actual IP of the website with the originating ReCaptcha.  This allows me to solve captchas and harvest them for later use.

I am now developing a React Native version however am struggling to determine if it's possible to map a RN WebView or similar to act as the website with the ReCaptcha on (example.com).

Is there a technology that can be used such as Appium or Detox that might be more suited to this task?

Answer (score 1):

Detox doesn’t support it because the underlying devices don’t support it. iOS simulator has no settings for configuring a proxy server. Instead, you should mock your APIs. Check out our mocking guide in the documentation.